# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Guilds') Node.js v18.16.1

Tags: javascript, discord, geolocation, bots

I want to create Discord Bot
but this `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,`
put me error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Guilds')`
how to fix?

**index.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
});
const prefix = '!';

const GEOLITE2_API_KEY = 'MY_KEY_LOL';
const GEOLITE2_BASE_URL = 'https://geolite.info/geoip/v2.1/';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return; // Ignore messages from bots
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return; // Ignore messages without the prefix

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'countryinfo') {
        const ip_address = args[0];
        if (!ip_address) {
            message.channel.send('Please provide an IP address.');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${GEOLITE2_BASE_URL}country/${ip_address}`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${GEOLITE2_API_KEY}`,
                },
            });
            const data = response.data;

            if (response.status === 200) {
                const country_name = data.country_name;
                const iso_code = data.iso_code;

                const infoMessage = `IP Address: ${ip_address}\nCountry: ${country_name}\nISO Code: ${iso_code}`;
                message.channel.send(infoMessage);
            } else {
                message.channel.send(`Error: Unable to fetch country information for ${ip_address}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            message.channel.send('An error occurred while fetching country information.');
        }
    } else if (command === 'cityinfo') {
        const ip_address = args[0];
        if (!ip_address) {
            message.channel.send('Please provide an IP address.');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${GEOLITE2_BASE_URL}city/${ip_address}`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${GEOLITE2_API_KEY}`,
                },
            });
            const data = response.data;

            if (response.status === 200) {
                const city_name = data.city_name;
                const region_name = data.region_name;

                const infoMessage = `IP Address: ${ip_address}\nCity: ${city_name}\nRegion: ${region_name}`;
                message.channel.send(infoMessage);
            } else {
                message.channel.send(`Error: Unable to fetch city information for ${ip_address}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            message.channel.send('An error occurred while fetching city information.');
        }
    }
});

client.login('I_DONT_KNOW');
```

**Error**

```
index.js:7
                GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Guilds')
    at Object.<anonymous> (\index.js:7:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.16.1
```

how to fix???

I want to fix this problem
If you want to use just contact me free IG:0markpnd_

Comment: what version of discord.js do you use?